# Views Slideshow: keeps showing all images below slider

Tags: views

It shows the normal slider on top... and then all of the images that are suppose to be sliding are stacked below it.

I've gone through several different tutorials and done them all the same way, and I'm still getting this. There has to be something simple that I'm doing wrong here.. but I don't know what it is.

I wanted to post a picture, but my reputation is only a 6..

Edit:   Just realized when you hover over these they change the top slide, like thumbnails normally do.  But I have no idea how to turn them off or change them to a different size.  I created an image style for this, but it apparently isn't working.

Edit x2:  It has nothing to do with the thumbnails. It just keeps showing all content that's suppose to be cycling.  For example, it's showing every number and every title.  Is there no CSS at all with Views Slideshow to not display things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured this out. I guess all I needed to do was make a post about it. On the toolbar go to Structure > Views > Your_Slider (whatever it's called) Under Format click on settings beside slideshow Scroll to the bottom. Go to Widgets and make sure there are no pagers selected here. Save and you're done.